Postgresql, JOIN on the same table with two values?
I need to pull data from various tables based on foreign key id's using both multiple JOINS and multiple WHERE clauses.
At the moment I have this (which is of course not working):
SELECT table_1.*
        FROM table_1
            JOIN table_2
            ON table_1.from = table_2.id
            WHERE table_2.name = 'from-city'
            
            JOIN table_2
            ON table_1.to = table_2.id
            WHERE table_2.name = 'to-city'
            
        ORDER BY table_1.id;

And I need to make this in a way that I can add tons of other WHERE CLAUSES in the future (think dynamic queries based on queryStrings [URLSearchParams]).
How would I go about 'thinking' of this problem to not shoot my self in the foot in the long run?
I saw that to use multiple joins you have to do something like:
SELECT table_1.*
        FROM table_1
            JOIN table_2
            ON table_1.from = table_2.id AND table_1.to = table_2.id
-- But this screws up my where clause 'logic' …
            WHERE table_2.name = 'from-city' ?  
            WHERE table_2.name = 'to-city'   ?
            
        ORDER BY table.id;

But I guess that's where you talk about different values, right?
I'd prefer if I could write something like:
SELECT table_1.*
        FROM table_1
            JOIN table_2
            ON table_1.from = table_2.id
            WHERE table_2.name = 'from-city'
            
            AND table_1.to = table_2.id
            WHERE table_2.name = 'to-city'
            
        ORDER BY table_1.id;

What would be the right 'mind set' in order for me to write queries in this more manageable, dynamic and readable way?
What have I tried?
I've only been googling the crap out of it, watching videos on complex sql queries, and wildly guessing – not really helping myself in that regard.

The correct syntax for joining the same table twice is giving it different alias names and thus be able to treat the two rows as if they were from different tables:
SELECT *
FROM table_1 t1
JOIN table_2 t2a ON t2a.id = t1.from and t2a.name = 'from-city'
JOIN table_2 t2b ON t2b.id = t1.to and t2b.name = 'to-city'
ORDER BY t1.id;

If, however, you only want to select data from the first table, then you need the second table only as filter criteria, and I would not join at all, but put the condition in the where clause where it belongs:
SELECT *
FROM table_1 t1
WHERE t1.from = (SELECT id FROM table_2 WHERE name = 'from-city')
  AND t1.to   = (SELECT id FROM table_2 WHERE name = 'to-city')
ORDER BY t1.id;


That's pretty much what I was looking for ... thanks. Baffled though, as how SQL makes my brain boil.

Yep, SQL can be a little overwhelming at first, with so many options how to write a query. But once you got used to it, it becomes very easy and the solution often comes to mind straight away.

At this point you may also want to check IN and EXISTS by the way: https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-tutorial/postgresql-in/ and https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-tutorial/postgresql-exists/
